# Array Json to List<MyObject> with Gson or Xtream

Tags: java, arrays, list, gson

Hello I had this follow json code.

```
[{"check":{"domain":"qwe.coedu.br"}},{"check":{"domain":"qwe.com.br"}},{"check":{"domain":"qwe.com"}}]"
```

How do to convert this json in my object

```
class Check {String domain , String status ...}
```

It return a `List<Check>`, but the Check attributes are null. See my code. with Gson.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type fooType = new TypeToken<Collection<Check>>(){}.getType();
    System.out.println(((List<Check>)gson.fromJson("[{\"check\":{\"status\":\"2\",\"domain\":\"william.com.br\"}}]", fooType)).get(0).getDomain());
```

When I debug my returned list, this contains all objects in list, but all with your attributes null.

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a customized converter, because you have a list of objects that holds a property named `check`. And this property is of a class that has the properties `domain` and `status`.

Two possibilities here:

1. **if you don't want to change the Json format, or you simply can't** probably write your own [`JsonDeserializer`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/r88/trunk/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html), in which you will instanciate your `Check` object and then set the properties by your own is the best choice;
2. or you could **modify your check class** in order to hold a `check` property of a type that holds a property named `domain` and another one `status`.

For the second case is pretty clear what needs to be done, but for the first case you could do something like:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Collection;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class GsonTestClass {

    static class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Check> {

        public Check deserialize(JsonElement arg0, Type arg1,
                JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
            JsonObject jsonObject = arg0.getAsJsonObject().get("check").getAsJsonObject();
            // this code could be improved with null checks and so on...
            return new Check( //
                    jsonObject.get("domain").getAsString(), //
                    jsonObject.get("status").getAsString() //
            );
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Check.class, new MyDeserializer()).create();
        String json = "[{\"check\":{\"status\":\"2\",\"domain\":\"william.com.br\"}}]";
        Type fooType = new TypeToken<Collection<Check>>() {}.getType();
        System.out.println((gson.fromJson(json, fooType)));
    }

    static class Check {

        private String domain;
        private String status;

        public Check() {
        }

        public Check(String domain, String status) {
            super();
            this.domain = domain;
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getDomain() {
            return domain;
        }

        public void setDomain(String domain) {
            this.domain = domain;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Check: " + domain + " - " + status;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Java class `Check` with its fields `domain` and `status` corresponds to

```
{"status":"2","domain":"william.com.br"}
```

in JSON, so a JSON "equivalent" of `List<Check>` would be

```
[{"status":"1","domain":"qwe.coedu.br"},{"status":"1","domain":"qwe.com.br"}]
```

Your JSON has another level of object nesting, where each list entry is an object with one property named `check`. Either restructure you JSON to remove the seemingly unnecessary nesting, or deserialize into e.g.

```
List<Map<String,Check>>
```

Comment: The problem is that I consume a rest webservice, but my container is Jboss 4.0.4GA and occurr problem with resteasy client. The Json return by webservice is that show above

Comment: I got with code Francisco Spaeth. But I got with idea too. I only encapsuled my Check class into a Test class and named my attribute like check. Example: class Test{private Check check;...}